# Git commands - how to get the code from master branch to my branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

I'm working on a group project where we have a branch for each member and a master branch.

My question is, how can I get the code that is in the master branch into my own branch locally? If you can tell me the commands I need to do? Been worried I will mess it up somehow.

I am using Git Bash and the project is on GitLab

Would be appreciated, I've searched online and I'm just getting more confused, hoping someone here could tell me more simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a git rebase:

```
git rebase <your-branch-name-here> master
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget to stash any unstaged changes by doing `git stash` before performing rebase. After rebase, do `git stash pop` to unload those changes. Mind you there might be merge conflicts depending what your local changes were.

Comment: Okay I will check out this command, what if I don't care about my branch I've not really done anything on it, I just want the masters code

Comment: Then you can just create a new branch and the entire master code will come through `git checkout master` and then `git checkout -b <your-new-branch-name>`